# Get product list of given category

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to get a list of products of a given category from WP_query, but it won't work like it should.

I've done this :

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'product_cat' => 17,
);
$products = new WP_Query($args);
```

But this returns **every** product from my shop ... I have also tried with 'cat', 'category' and 'category_name' attr with same result.

I've tried using tax_query :

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'terms'    => 17
    ),
);
$products = new WP_Query($args);
```

And this also returns **every products**
I have also tried with 'cat', 'category' and 'category_name' with same result.

I have managed using the following code to get regular posts from a given category.

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'cat'       => 22
);
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

A couple more things :

- I am certain I have the right category id.
- tax_query worked for the posts too
- edit : `tax_query` returns every products, ignoring my `product_cat` attr

  I have been looking to do this for days and tried every possible solution of similar questions on stack and other sites without success... Why doesn't it work for products ?

EDIT : the code snipet with `tax_query` was wrong so I changed it.

EDIT 2 : I have tried several new Things, here is the summary :

- disabled all custom hooks : same results
- instantiated a `WC_Product` manually by the id of an actual product as an argument. It shows that its `category_ids` attribute is empty, even though the product *does* have a category on the admin panel... and the category taxonomy page shows the right stuff too.
- when I do `var_dump(get_the_terms($postID, 'category'));` on a regular post it works fine

EDIT 3 :
 - disabled all plugins but Woocommerce with same result... 
 - when I do `var_dump(get_post_types());`, the product post type does not show. And so naturally, when I do `var_dump(get_object_taxonomies('product'));`, it returns an empty array.

Comment: `'cat'`, `'category'`, `'category_name'`, and `'product_cat'` won't work as arguments because product categories are a separate taxonomy to categories, and you need a `tax_query` to query custom taxonomies. There is nothing wrong with the code for the tax query I can see here. Either the ID actually is wrong, or `product` and `product_cat` aren't the right names for the post type and taxonomy. They would be if you're using WooCommerce. Are you?

Comment: Also make sure you're not using the `pre_get_posts` hook anywhere in such a way that could interfere with this query.

Comment: Did you try to add `'suppress_filters' => false` ? Just an idea from the top of my head. Don't know if there any filters in place to suppress since you haven't mentioned what you use for the products.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I do use woocommerce for this. for the category ID, I have checked the URL parameters in the admin panel when editing a category so it should be the right one. How do I find the right taxonomy for a product category then ?

@Beee `'suppress_filters` does not change anything

Comment: `product_cat` is correct for WooCommerce. Is this the actual code you’re using? Or an example? And issue could exist isn’t he actual code that’s not present in this example, because this code is fine.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I'm using this code as is. It is located in my child theme's function.php because I want to build output for a custom shortcode. Also, I do have some products saved in several different categories. 
I am working after a guy who has added some filter/hooks. Do you guys have an idea which could make this go wrong ?

Comment: Even If I use a non-existent category id 
It returns all the products with the tax_query version

Comment: "I am working after a guy who has added some filter/hooks." — maybe one of the hooks caused the issue? Try to disable one or more of the hooks, whichever you think may apply. Alternatively, try `var_dump( wc_get_products( array( 'category' => '{SLUG}', 'limit' => 1, ) ) );` (replace *{SLUG}* with the actual category slug). Just to see if it works using [`wc_get_products()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query).

Comment: I've tried your idea. I have disabled all custom hooks and tried your snippet @Sally and it returns an empty array. It turns out when I instantiate a WC_Product feeding the id of a product, its 'category_ids' attribute is empty, even though it *does* have a category on the admin panel... What I don't understand is, when I visit the category page, the products from this category and only from this category *are* displayed. So wordpress somehow manages to do this product by category query

Comment: Try switching to a different theme, then run the `WC_Product` query on that product you've tested. If it works, then keep looking for any code in your theme files which may be causing the issue. Otherwise, you can try deactivating plugins one by one, excluding WooCommerce. You can also re-assign the category to the product and query it using WooCommerce functions or WordPress native functions.

Comment: Ok @Sally and the others, thank you for your answers !
Sadly I was still not able to solve my problem... I have switched to Twenty-Seventeen theme, disabled all plugins but Woocommerce with same result...
I have discovered something else though, when I do `var_dump(get_post_types());`, the `product` post type does not show. And so naturally, when I do `var_dump(get_object_taxonomies('product'));`, it returns an empty array... any more clues ? I'm totally at a loss here...

Comment: Where are you running this code? If you're doing it too early then the post types and taxonomies will not have been registered yet.

Comment: Yes, Jacob is correct. Custom post types are normally registered during the `init` hook; so if you run the code prior to that hook being called, then that might be the cause of the problem. Try running the `tax_query` code you have in `woocommerce_loaded`. [Example](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_loaded/) Or other hooks such as `admin_init`, etc.

Comment: Oh yeah I was putting this code right into `functions.php` without using hooks at all... I put the code in a custom shortcode (so it gets executed after everything is initialized) and when the shortcode is called, the product post_type and its taxonomies show correctly.

When I use the tax_query code, it still returns every single post from my shop. But now, when I instantiate a `WC_product` with its id, the `category_ids` attributes is no longer empty !

I can manage with this for now but if anyone got a better solution, I'm taking it. I'll wait a bit before posting a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end my main problem turned out to be that I was executing code right into functions.php (for testing purpose). The code was executing before woocommerce was initialized and then was failing to fetch products correctly.
Despite that, I couldn't get Wp_Query to return only products of one given category. It was still returning every product from my database so I found a way around it.

```
$category; //this is the var containing the wanted category slug
$productPosts = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'product'
));

//I could have used $productPosts->have_posts() here but I decided not to use it in my particular context
foreach ($productPosts->posts as $p) {
    $currentProduct = new WC_Product_Variable($p->ID);

    //I can only access category ids with WC_Product so I'm building an array of category slugs instead
    foreach ($currentProduct->get_category_ids() as $catId) {
        if( $term = get_term_by( 'id', $catId, 'product_cat' ) ){
            array_push($categories, $term->name); //push it
        }
    }

    if(in_array($category, $categories)){ //if the current currentProduct has the asked category,
        //push it in $currentProduct into $products array
        array_push($products, $currentProduct);
    }
    else{//current product doesn't have asked category
    }
} //end foreach, we now have all products of asked category... in $products array
```

This works... But really, it feels wrong. I'm making several database queries for each product I want to include in my final array... Is this how woocommerce is supposed to work ?
Also, I'm not sure how i'm supposed to paginate with this data but anyway it's not my concern here...

There must be a better way to do this but I couldn't find it for now...

Answer (score 1):

I know, I'm too late to answer this question but it helps others.

```
$args = array(      
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                            'field'    => 'term_id',
                            'terms'    => array($cat_id1,$cat_id2),
                            ),
                        ),
            );

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

It's tested and worked on **WC 3.9.1**